# Timing Commands With Intervals and Durations

Tags: python

I have been working on passing a command to to the AT daemon. I got that that far and know how to pass the time to AT along with the command I wish to run. Now I would like to set a start time, a duration, and an interval. Here is the issue, I need to pass to AT the time in the following format Hour:Minute (e.g. 23:00).

Example:
If I wanted to start at 5pm (Start 17:00) and run for 2 hours (Run for 120 minutes) every 30th minute. So this would run the command at:
17:00
17:30
18:00
18:30
19:00

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate a list of hour:minute strings you can use the `datetime` module to do so.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> duration = datetime.timedelta(hours=2)
>>> interval = datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)
>>> start_time = datetime.datetime(2019, 2, 28, 17, 00, 0)
>>> times = []
>>> cur_time = start_time
>>> while cur_time <= (start_time + duration):
    times.append(cur_time)
    cur_time = cur_time + interval
>>> time_strings = [t.strftime("%H:%M") for t in times]
>>> time_strings
['17:00', '17:30', '18:00', '18:30', '19:00']
```

Comment: Awesome, as I said I am new to python but I think I get 95% of that. Thanks for the straight answer my friend! I think the rest I can figure out from here and adapt it to fit my needs just right.